# Apache : Debug mod_rewrite - without RewriteLog

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2.2

I have a situation with a host on which I can't edit the `httpd.conf` or vhost configuration. Therefore I can't enable rewrite logging.

It's apache 2.2. I've discussed the possibility of turning on logging at length with the hosting provider and its a no go.

Moving the code onto a local environment isn't a great option as its a legacy site with a mountain of un archived code and other assets strewn all over the place. Setting up a dev version is a last resort.

I'm looking for an alternative to `RewriteLog` if one exists.